# how to find the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^{2xc}}$

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit of
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^{2xc}}$$

Do I just apply L'hopital's rules?

$$=\frac{2xc+e^{xc}}{e^{2xc}2c}$$
$$=\frac{2c+e^{xc}c}{4c^2e^{2xc}}$$

$$=?$$

Comment: Note that if $c < 0$ or $=0$ then L'Hospital is not applicable - you need to get these cases separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying any limits, we have to make sure that the form is actually indeterminate. Let's say $c<0$.

Then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^{2xc}}$ is of the form $\frac{-\infty}{0}$ which is not really indeterminate and tends to $-\infty$.

Secondly if $c=0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^{2xc}}=-2$.

Finally, if $c>0$, the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^2xc}$ has the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. As a thumb rule, we divide by the highest infinity in the expression in the numerator and the denominator.

Hence, $L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2c+e^{xc}-3}{e^{2xc}}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{x^2c}{e^{2xc}}+e^{-xc}-3e^{-xc}\right]=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2xc}{e^{2xc}\cdot2c}-0-0=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{2xc}\cdot2c}=0$

Answer (score 2):

Apply L'Hospital's rule, like you did, then take out the $e^x$ from the numerator and the denominator. You'll get $$\frac{\frac{2xc}{e^x} + e^cc}{4c^2e^{2c}}$$

Which is now trivial to evaluate.

You could also have taken out the $e^x$ at the begining, or even separate the limit into the sum of three limits using the properties of limits which would let you evalutate them invidually.

Answer (score 2):

For $c<0$ notice that
\begin{align}
x^2c + e^{xc} -3&\rightarrow-\infty\\
e^{2xc}&\rightarrow\infty
\end{align}
Hence, the limit of the ration in this case is $-\infty$.

For $c>0$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2c + e^{xc} -3}{e^{2xc}} &= x^2ce^{-2xc}+ e^{-xc}-3e^{-2xc}
\end{align}

Then, the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ is $0$.

For $c=0$ the ratio is the constant $-2$